# Application Insights - operation_Id shows as not-null, but prints the value "None"

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I'm analyzing the performance of an Azure App Service using Application Insights.

I want to join the `requests` and `dependencies` tables, which I successfully do. However, there are some rows which get excluded, because `operation_Id` in the `dependencies` table has a weird value.

When I say "a weird value", I mean that the values for `operation_Id` sometimes appear to be not-null, yet when I print them out it says "None". Either way, this is certainly not the same as the ID in the `functions` table, so the join won't work.

```
dependencies
| where timestamp > ago(1d) and isnotnull(operation_Id)
| summarize count() by operation_Id
```

Gives us:

- operation_Id: None
- Count: 1796

Suggesting that all of the `operation_Id` values are not-null, yet are printed as "none".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got in touch with the Application Insights team, and they pointed out that `operation_Id` is of type string, and thus cannot be null. It looks like in these cases, it is an empty string. So if I replace `isnotnull` with `isnotempty` I get the expected results.

So the related issue is why empty strings were being shown as "None" - and that seems to be a bug with the Python-based client I was using :-)